# Java Swing add buttons group to JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a problem adding a group of buttons inside of JTabbedPane in Java Swing. There is no problem to add single radio button in to the pane, but when I trying to add a group of radio buttons, Eclipse shows me that "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (ButtonGroup)"

Here is the part of code:

```
  import java.awt.*;

  public class MainSystemInterface {

     final static String ADDCUSTOMER = "Add New Customer";
     final static String SEARCHCUSTOMER = "Search for a Customer";
     final static String EDITCUSTOMER = "Account Details";
     final static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jframe");

     public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {

        final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab(ADDCUSTOMER, addCustomerTab);

        JPanel addCustomerTab = new JPanel();

        JRadioButton rdbtnPremium = new JRadioButton("PREMIUM");
        rdbtnPremium.setBounds(397, 157, 71, 23);
        rdbtnPremium.setSelected(false);

        JRadioButton rdbtnBasic = new JRadioButton("BASIC");
        rdbtnBasic.setBounds(336, 157, 64, 23);
        rdbtnBasic.setSelected(true);

        //Group the radio buttons.
        ButtonGroup rdbtntgroup = new ButtonGroup();
        rdbtntgroup.add(rdbtnBasic);
        rdbtntgroup.add(rdbtnPremium);

        // Not working
        addCustomerTab.add(rdbtntgroup);

        //Working
        addCustomerTab.add(rdbtnBasic);
     }
  }
```

Also there is no problem to add buttons group to frame or JPanel.

Comment: Also you have another problem in the code you've posted, you didn't import the swing classes corresponding to the components you're using, like **JFrame**,  **JPanel**, **ButtonGroup**, **JRadioButton** and **JTabbedPane**

Comment: This is only a part of the code (I mention that). The whole code is 1000+ rows... I pas only a part of code related to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't see anything when you add the `ButtonGroup` to the `JPanel`. It is logcally group your 2 radio buttons. What you should do is add radio buttons to the button group as you already done and then add radio buttons to the `jpanel` and place them in appropriate places.

Comment: Here is the problem, this is not working.  I am trying to add created group of buttons to this panel and I am getting error on Eclipse: The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (ButtonGroup). I tried to fix that as Eclipse suggested, but without success.

Comment: Don't add button group to the JPanel. Add your JRadioButtons to the ButtonGroup and then add those radio buttons to the Jpnale

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the JRadioButtons themselves to a JPanel and then add that JPanel to your JTabbedPane.  The ButtonGroup is a logical construct whose sole purpose is to make sure that only one JRadioButton can be selected at a time. It is not a visible component, and so you cannot add the ButtonGroup to any container.

Comment: This is actually that I am trying to do... I created new JPannel addCustomer, than I am trying to add created group of buttons to this panel and I getting error on Eclipse: The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (ButtonGroup). I tried to fix that as Eclipse suggested, but without success. I also added those buttons separately to this panel, but the error is the same.

Comment: @Alonuch: **again**, your key misunderstanding with that error, is that you're adding a ButtonGroup to a GUI and not a JPanel, and this you cannot do. I don't know how to explain this any simpler than this.

Comment: @Alonuch: To clarify, you are adding a ButtonGroup to your JTabbedPane and again cannot do this. You should instead add the JPanel that you've added your buttons to. I'm sure that you can figure this out. Keep trying.